# Xcode 6 layout issues

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Recently, Apple Inc. has released new iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus devices with a new OS (iOS 8) and tons of API changes. As well as there are more available displays' resolutions, an application should support at least 3 of them, I'm talking about iPhone 5/5S, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. Xcode 6 follows another way it did in the previous version. Now, in most cases, you don't create a Scene for a concrete display size (e.g. 4 inch., 3.5 inch.) but you do create a form or a page sheet. It's basically bigger than even iPhone 6 plus resolution, due to a new way of maintaining layouts. As far as I'm considered, you must create layouts and only through them you can achieve supporting different resolutions.

What I am going for is a minor misunderstanding of how to setup my layouts to support at least those 3 devices I have listed above. The problem is being that I can support only iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus with the best performance (i.e. objects are placed just as I wanted them to be). But what do I do for iPhone 5/5S support? Are there any resources I can read to understand the thing of layouts better? I appreciate your help in advance!

P.S. I tried to use a particular form's size in Interface Builder (4.7 inch., 4.0 inch.), but as well works only for the same resolution or higher.

An example is below. I have got wanted result for iPhone 6 and wrong thing for iPhone 5S. 
[image][image]